# How To Perfect Angles in a Simple Rotation Tween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, interpolation, tween

I'm creating coroutine which tweens an objects rotation around a specific point over the course of a period of time.  The rotation portion works fine, the only issue is when I try to set the perfected angles to avoid gimbal lock.

```
protected bool _isRotating = false;

/// <summary>
/// Rotates the hand around a specific point
/// </summary>
/// <param name="point">The point to rotate around</param>
/// <param name="perspective">
/// The perspective view in which the transform occurs, by default this is Camera.Main
/// </param>
public IEnumerator RotateHand(GameHelper.Axis axis, bool isPositiveDirection, 
                              Vector3 isolatedRotationPoint, float inTime = 1f, 
                              int degrees = GameHelper.RIGHT_ANGLE_DEGREES,
                              Transform perspective = null)
{
    if (_isRotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    _isRotating = true;

    var targetPerspective = perspective ?? Camera.main.transform;

    int charge = isPositiveDirection ? 1 : -1;
    int normalizedDegrees = degrees * charge;

    var noralizedAxisVector = this.GetNormalizeHandVectors(axis, targetPerspective);

    var perfectAngles = transform.eulerAngles +(noralizedAxisVector * normalizedDegrees);


    float startTime = Time.time;
    float endTime = startTime + inTime;
    while (Time.time < endTime)
    {
        var delta = normalizedDegrees * (Time.deltaTime / inTime);
        transform.RotateAround(isolatedRotationPoint, noralizedAxisVector, delta);
        yield return null;
    }

    //correct end values for loss in floating point percision
    transform.eulerAngles = perfectedAngles;


    _isRotating = false;
}
```

It's weird because some of the time the object rotates completely correctly, which should mean I have some signs flipped, or my axis's are off.  This is the function which normalized axis's based off of your main perspective.

```
protected Vector3 GetNormalizeHandVectors(GameHelper.Axis axis, Transform perspective)
{
    var forward = perspective.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    forward = forward.normalized;

    switch (axis)
    {
        case GameHelper.Axis.X:
        {
            return perspective.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        }
        case GameHelper.Axis.Y:
        {
            return perspective.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
        }
        case GameHelper.Axis.Z:
        {
            return perspective.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);   
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Axis Not Found");
}
```

Does anyone know, how I can set the proper perfected angles?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but the problem of gimbal lock can also be solved when [Quaternions](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) are used instead of XYZ rotations. The class provides conversions to and from angle axis rotations.

Comment: I was going to use quaternions I figured out how to rotate but I couldn't figure out how to rotate around a point

Comment: If the point is given in local coordinates (relative to the object you wish to rotate), this can be done by:
1. Translating with the point coordinates;
2. Rotating the object using quaternions (use the AngleAxis method with `normalizedAxisVector` as axis);
3. Translating with the negative point coordinates

Comment: How would I calculate that?

Comment: Calculate what exactly?

Comment: Say you have the object you want to rotates quaternion, and the axis you want to rotate arounds quaternion,  how do you calculate the quaternion of transposed position across the axis

Comment: The documentation ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html)) might answer your question.